# Nvidia Gtx 755M - Cannot access secondary GPU Permission denied [13]

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, bumblebee

I installed bumblebee and the Nvidia 331 drivers. I ran glmark2 and expected it to launch but I got this error. How do I run a program on the Gtx 755m graphics card?

```
$optirun -vv glmark2
[  151.608987] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[  151.609208] [INFO]Configured driver: nvidia
[  151.609389] [DEBUG]optirun version 3.2.1 starting...
[  151.609408] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
[  151.609415] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[  151.609423] [DEBUG] X display: :8
[  151.609430] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/nvidia-331:/usr/lib32/nvidia-331
[  151.609438] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
[  151.609445] [DEBUG] Accel/display bridge: auto
[  151.609453] [DEBUG] VGL Compression: proxy
[  151.609461] [DEBUG] VGLrun extra options: 
[  151.609469] [DEBUG] Primus LD Path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
[  151.756765] [DEBUG]Using auto-detected bridge primus
[  155.608196] [INFO]Response: No - error: [XORG] (EE) intel(0): [drm] failed to set drm interface version: Permission denied [13].

[  155.608238] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) intel(0): [drm] failed to set drm interface version: Permission denied [13].

[  155.608258] [DEBUG]Socket closed.
[  155.608291] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
[  155.608318] [DEBUG]Killing all remaining processes.
```

My Laptop Model Is the Y410P and has A Nvidia gtx 755M

**My VGA compatible Controllers are:**

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 755M] (rev a1)
```

**System.log**

```
Io acpid: client connected from 3846[0:999]
Nov  4 20:23:31 Io acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Nov  4 20:23:34 Io bumblebeed[2023]: [XORG] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
Nov  4 20:23:34 Io bumblebeed[2023]: [XORG] (WW) "xmir" is not to be loaded by default. Skipping.
Nov  4 20:23:34 Io bumblebeed[2023]: [XORG] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
Nov  4 20:23:34 Io bumblebeed[2023]: [XORG] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
Nov  4 20:23:34 Io bumblebeed[2023]: [XORG] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
Nov  4 20:23:34 Io bumblebeed[2023]: [XORG] (EE) intel(0): [drm] failed to set drm interface version: Permission denied [13].
Nov  4 20:23:34 Io bumblebeed[2023]: [XORG] (EE) intel(0): Failed to claim DRM device.
Nov  4 20:23:34 Io bumblebeed[2023]: [XORG] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
Nov  4 20:23:34 Io bumblebeed[2023]: [XORG] (EE) 
Nov  4 20:23:34 Io bumblebeed[2023]: [XORG] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
Nov  4 20:23:34 Io bumblebeed[2023]: [XORG] (EE) 
Nov  4 20:23:34 Io bumblebeed[2023]: [XORG] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.8.log" for additional information.
Nov  4 20:23:34 Io bumblebeed[2023]: [XORG] (EE) 
Nov  4 20:23:34 Io bumblebeed[2023]: [XORG] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
Nov  4 20:23:34 Io bumblebeed[2023]: X did not start properly

Io kernel: [    0.424070] pci 0000:00:01.0: [8086:0c01] type 01 class 0x060400
Nov 15 16:35:41 Io kernel: [    0.424103] pci 0000:00:01.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
Nov 15 16:35:41 Io kernel: [    0.424195] pci 0000:00:01.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
Nov 15 16:35:41 Io kernel: [    0.424230] pci 0000:00:02.0: [8086:0416] type 00 class 0x030000
Nov 15 16:35:41 Io kernel: [    0.424240] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xc2000000-0xc23fffff 64bit]
Nov 15 16:35:41 Io kernel: [    0.424246] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0xb0000000-0xbfffffff 64bit pref]
Nov 15 16:35:41 Io kernel: [    0.424250] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 0x20: [io  0x5000-0x503f]
Nov 15 16:35:41 Io kernel: [    0.424370] pci 0000:00:03.0: [8086:0c0c] type 00 class 0x040300
Nov 15 16:35:41 Io kernel: [    0.424378] pci 0000:00:03.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xc2610000-0xc2613fff 64bit]
Nov 15 16:35:41 Io kernel: [    0.424521] pci 0000:00:14.0: [8086:8c31] type 00 class 0x0c0330
Nov 15 16:35:41 Io kernel: [    0.424541] pci 0000:00:14.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xc2600000-0xc260ffff 64bit]
Nov 15 16:35:41 Io kernel: [    0.424600] pci 0000:00:14.0: PME# supported from D3hot D3cold
Nov 15 16:35:41 Io kernel: [    0.424693] pci 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI

bbswitch: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
Nov 15 16:35:41 Io kernel: [   10.407511] bbswitch: version 0.7
Nov 15 16:35:41 Io kernel: [   10.407516] bbswitch: Found integrated VGA device 0000:00:02.0: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0
Nov 15 16:35:41 Io kernel: [   10.407520] bbswitch: Found discrete VGA device 0000:01:00.0: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP
Nov 15 16:35:41 Io kernel: [   10.407529] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
Nov 15 16:35:41 Io kernel: [   10.407582] bbswitch: detected an Optimus _DSM function
Nov 15 16:35:41 Io kernel: [   10.407590] pci 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
Nov 15 16:35:41 Io kernel: [   10.407626] bbswitch: disabling discrete graphics
Nov 15 16:35:41 Io kernel: [   10.407629] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
Nov 15 16:35:41 Io kernel: [   10.425803] bbswitch: Succesfully loaded. Discrete card 0000:01:00.0 is off
```

**Xorg.8.log**

```
[  1440.933] 
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
[  1440.933] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  1440.933] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-61-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[  1440.933] Current Operating System: Linux Io 3.16.0-24-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 28 13:07:32 UTC 2014 x86_64
[  1440.933] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-24-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=5b9b1a5b-a812-4478-9e57-49679c2d4cfa ro acpi=force quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[  1440.933] Build Date: 30 July 2014  12:21:54AM
[  1440.933] xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[  1440.933] Current version of pixman: 0.32.4
[  1440.933]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  1440.933] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  1440.933] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.8.log", Time: Tue Nov  4 20:00:32 2014
[  1440.933] (++) Using config file: "/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia"
[  1440.933] (++) Using config directory: "/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d"
[  1440.933] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  1440.933] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[  1440.933] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen" (0)
[  1440.933] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Configured Monitor"
[  1440.934] (**) |   |-->Device "Configured Video Device"
[  1440.934] (**) Option "AutoAddDevices" "false"
[  1440.934] (**) Option "AutoAddGPU" "false"
[  1440.934] (**) Not automatically adding devices
[  1440.934] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  1440.934] (**) Not automatically adding GPU devices
[  1440.934] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[  1440.934]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1440.934] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[  1440.934]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1440.934] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[  1440.934]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1440.934] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[  1440.934]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1440.934] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[  1440.934]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1440.934] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[  1440.934] (++) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/nvidia-331/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  1440.934] (==) |-->Input Device "<default pointer>"
[  1440.934] (==) |-->Input Device "<default keyboard>"
[  1440.934] (==) The core pointer device wasn't specified explicitly in the layout.
    Using the default mouse configuration.
[  1440.934] (==) The core keyboard device wasn't specified explicitly in the layout.
    Using the default keyboard configuration.
[  1440.934] (II) Loader magic: 0x7f009d996d40
[  1440.934] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  1440.934]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  1440.934]    X.Org Video Driver: 15.0
[  1440.934]    X.Org XInput driver : 20.0
[  1440.934]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[  1440.934] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[  1440.934] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[  1440.935] (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 10de:0fcd:17aa:3801 rev 161, Mem @ 0xc0000000/16777216, 0x90000000/268435456, 0xa0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00004000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension Present
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension DRI3
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[  1440.935] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[  1440.935] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[  1440.935] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[  1440.935] (WW) "xmir" is not to be loaded by default. Skipping.
[  1440.935] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  1440.935] (II) Loading /usr/lib/nvidia-331/xorg/libglx.so
[  1440.941] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[  1440.941]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[  1440.941]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[  1440.941] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  331.89  Tue Jul  1 11:25:05 PDT 2014
[  1440.941] Loading extension GLX
[  1440.941] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[  1440.941] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 1
[  1440.941] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 2
[  1440.941] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 3
[  1440.941] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 4
[  1440.941] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 5
[  1440.941] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 6
[  1440.941] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[  1440.941] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[  1440.941] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[  1440.941] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1440.941]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 2.99.916
[  1440.941]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1440.941]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[  1440.941] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[  1440.941] (II) Loading /usr/lib/nvidia-331/xorg/nvidia_drv.so
[  1440.942] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[  1440.942]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[  1440.942]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1440.942] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[  1440.942] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[  1440.942] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1440.942]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.0.11
[  1440.942]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1440.942]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[  1440.942] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[  1440.942] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[  1440.942] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1440.942]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.8.1
[  1440.942]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1440.942]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[  1440.942] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[  1440.942] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[  1440.942] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1440.942]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.4.4
[  1440.942]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1440.942]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[  1440.942] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[  1440.942] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[  1440.942] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1440.942]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.3.3
[  1440.942]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1440.942]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[  1440.942] (II) LoadModule: "mouse"
[  1440.942] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/mouse_drv.so
[  1440.942] (II) Module mouse: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1440.942]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 1.9.0
[  1440.942]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[  1440.942]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 20.0
[  1440.942] (II) LoadModule: "kbd"
[  1440.943] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module kbd
[  1440.943] (II) UnloadModule: "kbd"
[  1440.943] (II) Unloading kbd
[  1440.943] (EE) Failed to load module "kbd" (module does not exist, 0)
[  1440.943] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[  1440.943] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics: 2000-6000
[  1440.943] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics: 5100, 6100
[  1440.943] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics: 5200, 6200, P6300
[  1440.943] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  331.89  Tue Jul  1 11:06:25 PDT 2014
[  1440.943] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[  1440.943] (II) NOUVEAU driver 
[  1440.943] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[  1440.943]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[  1440.943]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[  1440.943]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[  1440.943]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[  1440.943]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[  1440.943]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[  1440.943]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[  1440.943]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[  1440.943]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[  1440.943]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[  1440.943]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[  1440.943]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[  1440.943]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[  1440.943] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[  1440.943] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[  1440.943] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[  1440.943] (--) using VT number 7

[  1440.943] (II) intel(0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20080730
[  1440.943] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.916+git20141101.cc3b8a54-0ubuntu0sarvatt~trusty (Robert Hooker <sarvatt@ubuntu.com>)
[  1440.943] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled for use with valgrind
[  1440.943] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[  1440.944] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[  1440.944] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[  1440.944] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[  1440.944] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[  1440.944] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1440.944]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 0.0.2
[  1440.944]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[  1440.944] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[  1443.172] (EE) intel(0): [drm] failed to set drm interface version: Permission denied [13].
[  1443.172] (II) intel(0): [drm] Contents of '/sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/clients':
[  1443.172] (II) intel(0): [drm] a dev pid    uid  magic
[  1443.172] (II) intel(0): [drm] 
[  1443.172] (II) intel(0): [drm] y   0  3803     0          0
[  1443.172] (II) intel(0): [drm] y   0  2799  1000          4
[  1443.172] (II) intel(0): [drm] y   0  1952     0          0
[  1443.172] (EE) intel(0): Failed to claim DRM device.
[  1443.172] (II) UnloadModule: "intel"
[  1443.172] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[  1443.172] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[  1443.172] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[  1443.172] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[  1443.172] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.8.log" for additional information.
[  1443.172] (EE) 
[  1443.173] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

**lsmod**

```
$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
nvidia              10728519  0 
pci_stub               12622  1 
vboxpci                23256  0 
vboxnetadp             25670  0 
vboxnetflt             27605  0 
vboxdrv               418013  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
bnep                   19543  2 
rfcomm                 69509  8 
binfmt_misc            17468  1 
arc4                   12608  2 
iwlmvm                218027  0 
mac80211              660592  1 iwlmvm
uvcvideo               81065  0 
intel_rapl             18783  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         59104  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_common            15682  1 videobuf2_core
videodev              149725  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14205  0 
media                  21963  2 uvcvideo,videodev
intel_powerclamp       18786  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     47547  1 
kvm_intel             143553  0 
kvm                   459843  1 kvm_intel
iwlwifi               182909  1 iwlmvm
i915                  917618  7 
btusb                  32448  0 
bluetooth             446190  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
6lowpan_iphc           18702  1 bluetooth
snd_hda_codec_realtek    76887  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    68914  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
crct10dif_pclmul       14307  0 
snd_hda_intel          30379  5 
snd_hda_controller     35152  1 snd_hda_intel
drm_kms_helper         61627  1 i915
drm                   310919  7 i915,drm_kms_helper,nvidia
i2c_algo_bit           13406  1 i915
crc32_pclmul           13133  0 
snd_hda_codec         139675  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_hwdep              17698  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               104102  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_seq_midi           13564  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30876  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                67224  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
cfg80211              510218  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
snd_timer              29513  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
ghash_clmulni_intel    13230  0 
snd                    87611  21 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
soundcore              15052  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
mei_me                 19742  0 
aesni_intel           152552  1 
aes_x86_64             17131  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    13287  1 aesni_intel
mei                    87931  1 mei_me
joydev                 17344  0 
serio_raw              13434  0 
ideapad_laptop         18278  0 
gf128mul               14951  1 lrw
lpc_ich                21093  0 
shpchp                 37040  0 
glue_helper            13944  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20360  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
sparse_keymap          13948  1 ideapad_laptop
parport_pc             32741  0 
ppdev                  17671  0 
coretemp               13441  0 
wmi                    19193  0 
video                  20128  1 i915
mac_hid                13227  0 
bbswitch               13943  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42299  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1 
psmouse               106548  0 
ahci                   34062  3 
alx                    36680  0 
libahci                32424  1 ahci
mdio                   13561  1 alx
```

**bumblebee.conf**

```
# Configuration file for Bumblebee. Values should **not** be put between quotes

## Server options. Any change made in this section will need a server restart
# to take effect.
[bumblebeed]
# The secondary Xorg server DISPLAY number
VirtualDisplay=:8
# Should the unused Xorg server be kept running? Set this to true if waiting
# for X to be ready is too long and don't need power management at all.
KeepUnusedXServer=false
# The name of the Bumbleblee server group name (GID name)
ServerGroup=bumblebee
# Card power state at exit. Set to false if the card shoud be ON when Bumblebee
# server exits.
TurnCardOffAtExit=false
# The default behavior of '-f' option on optirun. If set to "true", '-f' will
# be ignored.
NoEcoModeOverride=false
# The Driver used by Bumblebee server. If this value is not set (or empty),
# auto-detection is performed. The available drivers are nvidia and nouveau
# (See also the driver-specific sections below)
Driver=nvidia
# Directory with a dummy config file to pass as a -configdir to secondary X
XorgConfDir=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d

## Client options. Will take effect on the next optirun executed.
[optirun]
# Acceleration/ rendering bridge, possible values are auto, virtualgl and
# primus.
Bridge=auto
# The method used for VirtualGL to transport frames between X servers.
# Possible values are proxy, jpeg, rgb, xv and yuv.
VGLTransport=proxy
# List of paths which are searched for the primus libGL.so.1 when using
# the primus bridge
PrimusLibraryPath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
# Should the program run under optirun even if Bumblebee server or nvidia card
# is not available?
AllowFallbackToIGC=false


# Driver-specific settings are grouped under [driver-NAME]. The sections are
# parsed if the Driver setting in [bumblebeed] is set to NAME (or if auto-
# detection resolves to NAME).
# PMMethod: method to use for saving power by disabling the nvidia card, valid
# values are: auto - automatically detect which PM method to use
#         bbswitch - new in BB 3, recommended if available
#       switcheroo - vga_switcheroo method, use at your own risk
#             none - disable PM completely
# https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Comparison-of-PM-methods

## Section with nvidia driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nvidia
[driver-nvidia]
# Module name to load, defaults to Driver if empty or unset
KernelDriver=nvidia-331
PMMethod=auto
# colon-separated path to the nvidia libraries
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-331:/usr/lib32/nvidia-331
# comma-separated path of the directory containing nvidia_drv.so and the
# default Xorg modules path
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-331/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

## Section with nouveau driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nouveau
[driver-nouveau]
KernelDriver=nouveau
PMMethod=auto
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau
```

**xorg.conf.nvidia**

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier  "Layout0"
    Option      "AutoAddDevices" "false"
    Option      "AutoAddGPU" "false"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "DiscreteNvidia"
    Driver      "nvidia"
    VendorName  "NVIDIA Corporation"

#   If the X server does not automatically detect your VGA device,
#   you can manually set it here.
#   To get the BusID prop, run `lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D'` and input the data
#   as you see in the commented example.
#   This Setting may be needed in some platforms with more than one
#   nvidia card, which may confuse the proprietary driver (e.g.,
#   trying to take ownership of the wrong device). Also needed on Ubuntu 13.04.
    BusID "PCI:01:00:0"

#   Setting ProbeAllGpus to false prevents the new proprietary driver
#   instance spawned to try to control the integrated graphics card,
#   which is already being managed outside bumblebee.
#   This option doesn't hurt and it is required on platforms running
#   more than one nvidia graphics card with the proprietary driver.
#   (E.g. Macbook Pro pre-2010 with nVidia 9400M + 9600M GT).
#   If this option is not set, the new Xorg may blacken the screen and
#   render it unusable (unless you have some way to run killall Xorg).
    Option "ProbeAllGpus" "false"

    Option "NoLogo" "true"
    Option "UseEDID" "false"
    Option "UseDisplayDevice" "none"
EndSection
```

Comment: maybe take a read thru here - https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/580

Comment: I did read through the bug report and tried it and it did not work, it still has the same error.

Comment: OK I re installed Ubuntu and it now works, YAY. I still don't know why It did not work before.